# Configure next-auth getProviders error with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm new to Typescript and I wactch a tutorial that use next-auth, but since I following the tutorial with Typescript, I encounter this error when using getProviders function.

[image]

[image]

As you can see when I try to update the state it show an error. What is the cause and how can I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The state you defined infers that it'll be only null. You need to add type to that state such as `useState<T>`. Instead of T, you can copy and paste the typeof response

Answer (score 0):

this is your `useState`

```
 const [providers,setProvider]=useState(null)
```

if you hover over `providers`, its type is referred as

```
 const providers: null
```

But then you are setting providers with `getProviders`. this is type for `getProviders`

```
function getProviders(): Promise<Record<LiteralUnion<BuiltInProviderType, string>, ClientSafeProvider> | null>
```

you should set the state like this:

```
 import { signIn, getProviders ,LiteralUnion,ClientSafeProvider} from "next-auth/react";
 import { BuiltInProviderType } from "next-auth/providers";


const [providers, setProvider] = React.useState<Record<
           LiteralUnion<BuiltInProviderType, string>,ClientSafeProvider > | null>(null);
```